# Visual Studio Select Python Interpreter error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Am trying to use visual studio to run my python notebook. I have setup my venv.

I managed to select my Python interpreter in visual studio code using the ctrl + shift + p function to the specific python script in my newly made venv as per image below

[image]

But the kernel still remains the same as per image below

[image]

Appreciate any help to workaround this. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

My jupyter extension version is v2022.9.1303220346.
If your are pre-release version. You can switch to release version.

And you can try the following way to find python interpreter.
Open your settins and search for `Python Path`.

[image]

Enter the absolute path here manually.